# Is there any way to express truncation function into max and min function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Define 
$$f_{KL}(x) = \begin{cases} K & \text{if } f(x)<K\\
f(x) & \text{if } K\leq f(x) \leq L \\
L & \text{if } f(x)>L
\end{cases}$$

I know that 
$$ f_K (x) =\begin{cases} K& \text{if } f(x)<K \\
f(x) &\text{if } f(x)\geq K\end{cases}$$
can be expressed as $f_K (x) =\max\{f(x),K\}$. How can I express $f_{KL}$ in terms of $\max,\min$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_{KL} (x) =\min\{\max\{f(x),K\},L\}$

Indeed if $f(x)<K$ then $\{\max\{f(x),K\}=K$ and $\min\{\max\{f(x),K\},L\}=K=f_{KL}(x)$.
Do the same for the other cases.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can prove some theorem. I will accept the answer in 20 mins due to Math stackexchange policy.

Comment: I am glad to help :).